# Nav button needs to go form the last view to the first view

Tags: swift, xcode

[image: Visual view of project]

Hello, I have provided the link above to show a visual view of what I am trying to accomplish. So each button is a segue to the next view except the last button is not which is intended. The last two views with the back buttons at the top that are automatically included because of the nav controller I want to have those back buttons go to the first view controller. How can I do this either with xcode and swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all the navigation controller then use this code

Put this code in the button selector method

```
self.navigationController!.viewControllers.removeAll()
```

OR

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

OR

If you don’t have a Navigation Controller and use dismissViewController method, you still can use:

```
view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now comes the back button code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var backbutton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    backbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "BackButton.png"), forState: .Normal) // Any image can be used. download back button image from any site or whatever you wanna use.
    backbutton.setTitle("Back", forState: .Normal)
    backbutton.setTitleColor(backbutton.tintColor, forState: .Normal) // You can change the TitleColor
    backbutton.addTarget(self, action: "backAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backbutton)
}

func backAction() -> Void {        
   //here put code from above whichever you wanna use for example I'm using one

   self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Let me know which one you used.

Comment: Your post has given me some deeper insight on what I need to do I will be right back to try this.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: So I am probably just missing something small here the  self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) does work but when I go to the 4th view controller it just goes back to the first view. When I set it to false it makes the button I have on that view on click goes back to the first view controller. So it seems like I need to setup some logic to where it doesn't do that. Working on that now.

Comment: but that is what we want right? that if we click on any of the navigation back button , it should go to the first view controller? or am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct the goal is to have the back button in the nav to go back to the first view controller.

Comment: so if you have place above code in all of the view controller except first then it should work as expected. Oh I think I got it. you are saying about the button inside first VC is working weird.

Comment: It probably will :) I just need to mess with the code a little bit more. I will check mark once I get it to work.